# calculate distance on map in picturebox

Tags: c#

I have a map from google maps imported in picturebox (the scale is 200m = 1.5cm).Start point is at(46.46705, 15.7411) and end point at(46.4590, 15.75150). This is how i calculated distance :

```
enter code here 
double lat1 = 46.46705 * (Math.PI/180);
double lon1 = 15.74111 * (Math.PI/180);
double lat2 = 46.45900 * (Math.PI/180);
double lon2 = 15.75150 * (Math.PI/180);
int R = 6371;
double d;
...............................................
var x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.Cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
var y = (lat2 - lat1);
d = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
d *= 1000; // get km
d = Math.Round(d, 2); // decimals
......................................
```

I'm asking how to calculate distance between start and random "end" point, which is smaller than end point(end of distance)? The start point is on coordinates (49,49) the end point is on coordinates (291,328). I don't have any other informations. Thank you for hlep.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to convert image coordinates to lat/long before executing your function.

This can be done with [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to go from horizontal coordinate to longitude, and vertical coordinate to latitude.